Shared Folders and Shared Clipboard is not working. Ubuntu 24.04 in VirtualBox 7.0.18 on Windows 11
I have VirtualBox (7.0.18) installed on Windows 11.
I added the Ubuntu 24.04 VM.
I see that Shared Folders and Shared Clipboard is not working.
I enabled Shared Clipboard bi-directional and also Shared folders in the VirtualBox menu.
But they are not visible to each other. Text copied from Windows is not seen in Ubuntu, and vice versa.
I installed the Guest Extensions



UPDATE:
From @David's mention and link,
I installed Ubuntu 22.04.4 on the existing VirtualBox 7.0.18
But I am now seeing a black screen. See below.


The Virtual Box forum clearly states that version and Ubuntu 24.04 do not like each other. https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=111556 Take a look and using a bit older version of Virtual Box might fix it for you.

@David Thanks. I shall keep the VirtualBox version and downgrade Ubuntu. Ubuntu 22.04 worked fine with VirtualBox 7.0.18

@David I downgraded and now I am seeing a black screen. See edited question for screenshot.

Created a new question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1518817/ubuntu-22-04-freezes-with-vb-7-0-18
