Ubuntu 22.04 freezes with VirtualBox 7.0.18
Since the forums mention there is a freeze when you have Ubuntu 24.04 with VirtualBox 7.0.18
I downgraded to Ubuntu 22.04.
I am seeing a freeze and this error message just before the freeze.



It is not a generic problem. I have a 22.04 virtual machine running just fine on VB 7.0.18.Did you try switching the graphics controller per the message?

I have had no issues with Version 7.0.18_Ubuntu r162988 of virtualbox on my system so I have no idea what you mean by freeze so I don't know what you mean.  (this applies to 22.04, 23.10 & 24.04 too)

@guiverc if you see the link posted by David, others have reported a freeze too https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=111556

@OrganicMarble I do not see graphics controller mentioned in the message at all. How to switch it out? Should I look in Settings for VirtualBox or Ubuntu?

The last error message in the 2nd picture you posted. It's a VB setting. The link in your comment also mentions switching the graphics controller.
